# Free gui-based math software to work with matrices

Tags: windows, gui, math

I am studiying *linear algebra* and during my studies have a need to do simple calculations on matrices, e.g.:

- multiple couple of matrices
- invert a matrix
- etc

I am looking for something free and rather simple (although I have some experience with MathCAD) to assist me with calculations.

P.S. I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) has a free 'Programming Lab' with, among other things, vector and matrix math.

That's not 'on' your Windows system, of course.

Comment: I don't really care for where it is, maybe even better if off my PC) Thx for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is quite powerful, comparable to Matlab (in a sense).
The learning curve is a bit steep, however if you are familiar with Matlab and/or MathCAD it might be easier to pick it up.

[image]